# how to get the value of table row in dropdownlist by clicking o the table row

Tags: javascript, php, html

*I want my dropdownlist to be filled with the value of table row when i click on table row and i am able to get the data in simple textbox by clicking on row but i am unable to fill the dropdownlist when i click on table row my code is below:*

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
    function showRow(row) {
        var x=row.cells;
        document.getElementById("id").value = x[0].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("date").value = x[1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("name").value = x[2].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("container").value = x[3].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("trip").value = x[4].innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Container</th>
        <th>Jobs</th>
    </tr>
    <tr onClick="javascript:showRow(this);">
        <td><?php echo $row->cust_id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->cust_date;?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row->c_name;?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row->container_id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->trip_id;?></td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control col-md-2" id="date">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Customer</label>
<select class="form-control" name="cust" id="cust">
    <?php 
        foreach($cust as $row) { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->c_id.'">'.$row->c_name.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: (1) Don't dump your server-side code as-is. Post only the generated markup. (2) What do you mean by *fill*? You want to change the options and replace with the one in the current row? (3) What do you want to pick up from the row? The entire row? What cells should go into the select?

Comment: I want to pick up the value of table row for example my column name is customer and it's value is "Ali" of that row so i want that to be filled in dropdownlist.

Comment: "*[..]i want that to be filled in dropdownlist*" -- *Filled* or *Selected* ?

Comment: Sorry i meant select the value

Comment: Are you looking for something like this -- https://jsfiddle.net/bk1omnt3/ ?